# Передача данных из фрагмента в Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, activity

Имеется layout-файл с `TextView` без текста:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.test.test.Info"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Также есть класс, связанный с данным layout-файлом:

```
public class Info extends AppCompatActivity
{
    TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_info);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }
```

Наконец, имеется класс, наследующий ListFragment:

```
public class List extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment
{
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1, adapter2;
    Intent toInfoClass;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context)
    {
        super.onAttach(context);
        adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.test1));
        adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.test2));
        toInfoClass = new Intent(getActivity(), Info.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(adapter1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        if (getListAdapter() == adapter1)
        {
            switch (position)
            {
            case 0:
                setListAdapter(adapter2);
                break;
            case 1:
                startActivity(toInfoClass);
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (getListAdapter() == adapter2)
        {
            switch (position)
            {
                case 0:
                    startActivity(toInfoClass);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на пункт списка, в `TextView` устанавливался какой-либо текст? Например, если выбран `adapter1`, осуществляется переход в `Activity` и в `TextView` указывается текст: "Выбран адаптер 1". Если выбран `adapter2`, то вместе с переходом текст меняется на "Выбран адаптер 2".

Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Фрагмент располагается в той же активити, в которой надо изменить текст или это 2 разных активити?

Comment: Нет, это 2 разных Activity

Comment: Тогда вам надо использовать передачу параметров через ```Intent```, смотрите ответ IEVGEN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передайте информацию в `Activity` с помощью `Intent extras`.
Перед `startActivity(toInfoClass)` добавьте

```
toInfoClass.putExtra("adapterMessage",getString(R.string.firstAdapterMsg));
```

Где `R.string.firstAdapterMsg` -- `id` вашего строкого ресурса из `res/values/strings.xml` Ну или передайте непосредственно строку как параметр. 
В `onStart()` `Activity` соответсвующей добавьте следующий код:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null) {
    textView.setText(extras.getString("adapterMessage");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Тут уже советовали не очень красивое решение в виде `((Info) getActivity()).имя_метода();`.

Но такое лучше делать интерфейсами.

```
public interface OnDataPass {
    public void onDataPass(String data);
}

public class Info extends AppCompatActivity implements OnDataPass {
   @Override
   public void onDataPass(String data) {
       Log.d("LOG","привет, я строка из фрагмента: " + data);
   }
   [...]
}
```

А в фрагменте:

```
private OnDataPass mDataPasser;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity a) {
    super.onAttach(a);
    mDataPasser = (OnDataPass) a;
}
```

Теперь, если вам надо отправить данные в `Activity` из вашего фрагмента, вызывайте:

```
mDataPasser.onDataPass("моя строка");
```

Comment: Благодарю за развёрнутый ответ. Буду очень признателен, если вы вкратце опишите преимущества реализации с помощью интерфейса.

Comment: @Win_D разграничение ответственности. Объекты должны иметь доступ только к тем свойствам, которые им необходимы.

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать очень просто. В Activity нужно описать метод который будет вызываться при клике и делать все что нужно. Для того что бы вызвать этот метод из фрагмента можно использовать следующий код

```
((Info) getActivity()).имя_метода();
```

Comment: Это очень плохая практика и возможна только для фрагмента, который находится в той же активити. В остальных случаях корректная работа этого способа никак не гарантируется.