# Реализация кнопки назад в тулбаре фрагмента

Tags: android

Из фрагмента 1 открывается фрагмент 2. Чтобы возвращаться назад по нажатию аппаратной кнопки, я реализовала -

в MainActivity

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

    if (count == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();

    } else {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
```

Все работает. Но у фрагмента 2 реализован свой тулбар и там есть кнопка назад. Не могу найти ответ как такое реализовать, везде тулбар часть активити.

код фрагмента 2

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootViewRead = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_data, container, false);
    toolbar = rootViewRead.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
    if (activity != null) {
        activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: попробуйте загуглить такое "Как передать данные из фрагмента в активити". Пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/486737/Передача-данных-из-фрагмента-в-activity

Comment: `getActivity().onBackPressed()`

Comment: @post_zeew не работает. сам onClick не срабатывает, даже если там допустим toast  показывать

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло убрать в разметке AppBarLayout -  `app:elevation="0dp"`, кнопки в тулбаре заработали.