# неясное поведение атрибута app:elevation

Tags: android

Я уже задавала вопрос [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/948207/Реализация-кнопки-назад-в-тулбаре-фрагмента/950051#950051](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/948207/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0/950051#950051)

Интересует почему такое странное поведение у атрибута app:elevation="0dp" и как решить задачу. Использую библиотеку androidx. Тулбар прозрачный. Остается тень. Когда прописываю app:elevation="0dp" тень пропадает, но кнопки тулбара, в том числе "назад" перестают реагировать.

Пробовала решить другими способами:
android:elevation="0dp"

прописать программно getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
не помогает.

макет такой:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/back_gray">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"/>

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/iv_like"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:src="@drawable/heart_outline"
                        android:visibility="visible"/>

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/iv_shared"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:src="@drawable/shared"
                        android:visibility="visible" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
 <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white">

                <TextView
                  ........./>

                <TextView
                 ........../>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

fragment.java

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_data, container, false);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();

    if (activity != null) {
        activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
      //  activity.getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
        activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        activity.getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getActivity().onBackPressed();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Может потому что `FrameLayout` в котором находится `Toolbar` имеет `elevation` больше 0? Устанавливая у тулбара `elevation = 0` вы тем самым переносите его на задний план. По идее вам нужно, наверное, установить у тулбар тот же `elevation`, что и у `FrameLayout`, чтобы избавиться от тени.

Comment: FrameLayout на весь экран. А я только разметку тулбара показала. Это сбило с толку. Обновила вопрос, добавив полный макет фрагмента.

Comment: @Moreau, по идее у вас `ScrollView` перекрывает тулбар и не пропускает клики, если у последнего `elevation` `0`. Тут может помочь уменьшение высоты `ScrollView`. Т.е. надо сделать так, чтобы он был под тулбаром, например, обернув тулбар и `ScrollView` в `LinearLayout`

Comment: Да, действительно. Если обернуть в linearLayout, то тень можно убрать и клики работают. Но тогда получается что скролл вью располагается под турбаром и текст будет в него упираться при прокрутке.  Если же скролл поднять выше тулбара, тогда текст вместе в тулбаром скроллится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделала родительским RelativeLayout и так как в нем элементы "наслаиваются" друг на друга, то сначала поместила ImageView с фоном, на него ScrollView и сверху прозрачный AppBarLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/back_gray">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

                    <TextView />

                    <TextView />

                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            app:elevation="0dp">


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:focusable="true"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageButton/>

                    <ImageButton/>
                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```